# AJAX not linking to PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

**I need to change a session value inside a JavaScript function so I decided to use AJAX. However, the call does not seem to be working. What is wrong?**

Index page setting default session value:

```
session_start();
if( is_null($_SESSION['lang']) ){
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'english';
}
```

AJAX call on index page:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'setlang.php?entry=0', false);
request.send();
```

The setlang.php file:

```
$entry = $_GET['entry'];
if($entry == 0){
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'english';
    Print_r ($_SESSION);
}else if($entry == 1){
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'japanese';
    Print_r ($_SESSION);
}
```

Nothing is being printed.  Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: What method are you using to view the response to the Ajax request?

Comment: None at the moment. Will that help debug the Ajax call?

Comment: Why was this close-voted?

Comment: @LuckyInJapan — If you aren't doing anything to determine what the response is, how do you know that nothing is being printed?

Comment: What happens, if you open the `setlang.php` file directly in your browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't actually have anyway to check the response (unless you omitted some part of your javascript).

Check MDN's [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)'s documentation.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onload = function() {
    alert(this.responseText);
}
request.onerror = function(e) {
    alert('Error : ' + e.target.status);
}
request.open('GET', 'setlang.php?entry=0', false);
request.send();
```

Also make sure you call `session_start();` in your php file.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I added this missing part to the ajax call.  When I fire off the javascript function no alert pops up.  What does this mean?

Comment: Open the developer console and see if there's anything printed in it, in chrome you can press `F12` to open it.

Comment: OH! I think I understand where I went wrong.  If I echo/print anything in that PHP file it will only show up in the alert box?

Comment: Once I fixed the errors that arose in the console, the php print session started popping up in the alert box showing the correct language setting.

Comment: anything you print in php will only be available in `onload`'s `this.responseText`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!  You filled some pretty important gaps in my ajax knowledge and really helped improve me as a coder.

Answer (score 0):

Add this on the top of setlang.php:

```
session_start();
```